# Remove tkinter window border

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've searched the web but I cant find an answer:

I just want to remove the border(that contains the tk icon, and the buttons(minimise,expand and close)) from the tkinter window,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
root.overrideredirect(True) # or 1 instead of True
```

Keep in mind, with this you actually cannot close the window from the titlebar(because titlebar is removed), and I dont think the window icon will appear in the taskbar either. Basically its like removing most possibilities in redirecting back to the window.

Hope this was of some help, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: yeah i have to wait 3 more minutes :), ill definitely do

Comment: @coderoftheday Would appreciate marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: sorry it took me so long, i forgot to do it yesterday